# PWM Mosfet (and help identifying the right one)

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am building a project to control a 12 V, 10 A heating system from a Raspberry Pi.

I have identified that I need to use a MOSFET transistor and I will control the output by using pulse width modulation (PWM).

Obviously there is a lot of choice in transistors and I want confirmation from the community that I'm going in the right direction or help with what I have done wrong.

Gate voltage should be no higher than 3.3 V.

Gate current cannot be higher than 8 mA.

I plan to control the output wattage with PWM (I don't know how that effects the discharge of the transistor?) at a voltage of 12 V and maximum drain current of 10 A.

So the transistor I have looked at is [2N6764](https://alltransistors.com/mosfet/transistor.php?transistor=62).

Now I haven't been able to find anywhere in the UK that sells them so is there a better fit (and how do I identify)?

Comment: Tip: put the transistor part number into the hyperlink's displayed text. As it stands we have to follow a link to know what transistor you have selected and that will put busy folks off. Use syntax `[Text to display](http://example.com)`.

Comment: As the 2N6764 seems to have a max. gate threshold voltage of 4V, you will not be able to drive that one with your 3.3V signal.

Comment: Sam. Can you define the over all system requirements for mass, temperature sensing accuracy, control speed? deg/sec. / minute?  Then we can see if PWM is right for you or just On off...

Comment: If you use an optocoupler between the logic control and the Mosfet you can insure that the 12V never has a chance of getting into your Pi system. The LED input side of the optocoupler can easily be driven by the 3.3V logic and the output side can be connected to the higher voltage to better switch the Mosfet.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I am planning on controlling my heated jacket on my motorcycle. I want to use the Pi so I can add sensors later and get a comfortable and consistent temp. The stock controller has Off/Low/Medium/High but very little details on what it does.

Comment: @Nedd I hadn't even considered an Optocoupler what a wonderful idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 99% efficiency choose **Ron <= 12 mOhm** = 1% of 12V/10A=1.2Ohm with logic level gate drive of 3.3V.

With millions of FET choices this usually means Vt (=Vgs(th)) is ~ <=1/3 of Vg=3.3 or **Vt< 1.1V** to start looking from with a filter range.